# Django: Radio buttons "checked" after validation

Tags: django, forms, validation, radio-button

I'm having a ModelForm with Django which works fine. It also validates fine, only problem: My input field (a couple of radio buttons) doesn't get checked="checked" after returning a bad validation, so the user has to go over the radio buttons again. Which seems stupid.

Is there any way to get Django to set checked="checked" on radio buttons on validation?

Comment: You'll need to show your view and template so we can see what what you are doing wrong.